# How to get the page id of a Facebook page

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any way to get the Facebook page id of any Facebook page. I have to open the Facebook page on the Facebook app but that requires the page id

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/113810631976867"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
}
```

Please guide for above.

Comment: your coding is fine , check that ID is valid or not

Comment: above is just an example, i want to know to the way of getting the page id.

Comment: you want to know that **"how to retrieve the pageID"**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes, want to know the same

Comment: finally I have one doubt -- in here you need page ID is progrmatically(unknown PageID) else automatically(already u known )

Comment: I need to found the page id of static page, whether programmatically or any other way, i am gonna use static page id in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manually Find PageID**

*Choice-1*

see this [link](http://findmyfbid.com), in this link add your page name it shows the output

*Choice-2*

**Step-1**

> Go to your FB page

**Step-2**

> Right-click on the image and copy the link!

**Step-3**

> Paste the link into the Address Bar in your browser, a text editor or anywhere else that’s handy
>
> Your Page’s or **Profile’s ID** is the number after the LAST period

output like

[image]

Comment: check the answer bro find the static Page ID

Comment: Hey your first link works, but 2nd may be i didn't understand how it works, and ofcourse i want to know can we find it programmatically

Comment: @iPhone6 -- in which Facebook SDK u used now

Comment: didn't get you buddy, i used fb sdk3.0. What i did was open an fb page copy link of its profile image then this is what i get "https://www.facebook.com/30daysofbiking/photos/a.153915104633086.31921.113810631976867/555840557773870/?type=1&source=11"

Comment: @iPhone6 -  this is your Facebook page ID **113810631976867** bro

Comment: ok bro thanks but one last questions only can we get it programmatically for any dynamic page?